# Added functionality not showing up in a COM object

Tags: vb.net, com, visual-foxpro

I have created a dll in VB.Net that is used in a Visual Foxpro application. Recently I added a few functions to help in sanitizing data and clearing input from a user-control and re-built the project. I am currently using Regasm to register the dll's and this seems to work fine. However when i register the dll, the new functionality does not show, making it seem like one is still using the old, previously registered dll. Is there something i'm not doing right?
Here's an excerpt of the code.

```
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch), ProgId("LPFPasserelle.FicheEtablissement")>
    Public Class FicheEtablissement
      Private mCreateInstitution As New CreateInstitution
       <ComRegisterFunction()>
    Public Shared Sub RegisterClass(ByVal key As String)

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(key)
    sb.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "")

    '// Open the CLSID\{guid} key for write access  
    Dim k As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), True)
    Dim ctrl As RegistryKey = k.CreateSubKey("Control")
    ctrl.Close()

    '// Next create the CodeBase entry - needed if not string named and GACced.  
    Dim inprocServer32 As RegistryKey = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", True)
    inprocServer32.SetValue("CodeBase", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
    inprocServer32.Close()

    k.Close()
End Sub

<ComUnregisterFunction()>
Public Shared Sub UnregisterClass(ByVal key As String)

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(key)
    sb.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "")

    '// Open HKCR\CLSID\{guid} for write access  
    Dim k As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), True)

    '// Delete the 'Control' key, but don't throw an exception if it does not exist  
    If k Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    k.DeleteSubKey("Control", False)

    '// Next open up InprocServer32  
    Dim inprocServer32 As RegistryKey = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", True)

    '// And delete the CodeBase key, again not throwing if missing   
    inprocServer32.DeleteSubKey("CodeBase", False)

    '// Finally close the main key   
    inprocServer32.Close()
    k.Close()

End Sub
```

The function for sanitizing string data that I added is below.

```
 Function SanitizeStringData(ByVal StringToSanitize As String)
    Dim mSanitizedString As String = String.Empty
    mSanitizedString = Trim(StringToSanitize)
    If Trim(StringToSanitize).Contains("'") Then
        mSanitizedString = Trim(StringToSanitize).Replace("'", "''")
    End If
    Return mSanitizedString
End Function
```

Comment: Are you unregistering the old assembly before registering the new? Are you sure you're pointing to the new assembly when you register?

Comment: Yes. The unregistering and registering is done from a batch file. I've even gone as far as creating and registering the .tlb files but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your sanitizing dll/COM issue, but for your sanitize string, I don't know why you are not just using VFP's function STRTRAN()

someString = [What's goin' on]

? STRTRAN( someString, "'", "''" )

will result in

What''s goin'' on

[Help on StrTran() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x9cw4z6s(v=vs.80).aspx)

[Another cool one is CHRTRAN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b93s4tbe(v=vs.80).aspx) and has a wide range of benefits from stripping invalid characters from strings to a pseudo encryption by replacing every character in a string to something else...

Comment: The dll is created in vb.net and contains all the functionality required to capture and save the data. The software that uses this dll is done in vfp. That's why I didn't use those functions - STRTRAN() and CHRTRAN()

Comment: @Jay... correct.. if you are using VFP to do the work and calling a VB.net dll, you don't NEED the vb.net DLL.  These are functions built INTO VFP by default and you can use them directly.  No need for outside dll functionality.

Comment: The task I needed to achieve could not be done from VFP, hence the .NET dll. Vfp is simply consuming the dll because the original software is done in VFP9